# $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ proof explanation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$: Note that a rational number $a$ can be represented in $\mathbb{R}$ by the constant sequence $[a,a,\ldots]$. The Archimedean property holds since $[a_n] > 0$ implies
that eventually $a_n \ge p > 0$, $\exists p \in Q$, so $[a_n] \ge [p/2] > 0$. Also, if $x = [a_n]$ then
$a_n \rightarrow x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, since for any $\epsilon > 0$, let $p\in  \mathbb{Q}$, $0 < p < \epsilon$, so
$$\exists N, n,m \ge N \implies |a_n − a_m| < p$$

$$\implies d(a_n, x) = d([a_n,a_n,\ldots],[a_1,a_2,\ldots])$$
$$= [|a_n − a_1|,|a_n − a_2|,\ldots]$$
$$< \epsilon.$$

Could some one explain to me why this justifies that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is there a particular part of this explanation you don't understand? For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, given any $\epsilon > 0$, you can find an $a_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $d(a_{n},x) \leq p <  \epsilon$. This is the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh i guess I don't understand the definition

Comment: @feyique What is unclear about the definition? $\mathbb{R}$ has a measure of closeness ($x$ is close to $y$ if $|x-y|$ is small). A subset $A$ is **dense** in $\mathbb{R}$ if given any point in $\mathbb{R}$ we can find points of $A$ arbitrarily close to it.

Comment: What is the purpose of $p$?